# What if sqlite3_open() returns an error AND a valid database connection?

Tags: sqlite

The documentation for sqlite3_open() says this:

"A database connection handle is usually returned in *ppDb, even if an error occurs."

Does this mean that if sqlite3_open() returns something other than SQLITE_OK AND a non null database handle that you owe a sqlite3_close() before attempting sqlite3_open() again?

If so, this could explain a problem I'm having where randomly a database fails to open because it is locked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to close the `sqlite3` connection object if it's returned as non null.

The [sqlite3_open() manual](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) is quite clear;

> Whether or not an error occurs when it is opened, resources associated with the database connection handle should be released by passing it to sqlite3_close() when it is no longer required.

At the very least, you'll have a memory leak of the `sqlite3` connection object itself if you don't, since [`sqlite3_close()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) frees that object and any resources allocated to it.